# Best way to loop through all possible combinations across multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, sql-server-2012

I have two simple tables:

`OrderStatus` and `OrderStage` that have a single primary key integer column of `OrderStatusID` and `OrderStageID` respectively. Each table returns about 5 rows.

What I'm trying to do is make a SELECT statement which counts the number of orders per OrderStatusID and OrderStageID combination. Here's an example:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(OrderID)
FROM
 Order
WHERE
 OrderStatusID = '1' and OrderStageID = '1'


SELECT 
 COUNT(OrderID)
FROM
 Order
WHERE
 OrderStatusID = '1' and OrderStageID = '2'

......
SELECT 
 COUNT(OrderID)
FROM
 Order
WHERE
 OrderStatusID = '4' and OrderStageID = '5'
```

Its getting tedious for me to have to write out 5x5 SQL statements to count the number of orders in each possible combination. And if someone adds more rows to the `OrderStatus` or `OrderStage` tables then I'll have to keep revisiting this code to add the new combinations.

The final presentation of this data will be in a 'tree' on a webpage quite similar to how Outlook displays a count of emails in your Inbox, Sent Items, Deleted etc within the mail panel. I using ColdFusion for my webpage. If I use a GROUP BY statement to get the data out, how would I then separately display each result row in ColdFusion? Would `<cfquery group="">` work?

It should return 0 or NULL for where there are no rows in the Order table for a given OrderStatusID and OrderStageID combination. This is why I was using separate SELECT statements for each possible combination.

Comment: hm, why you don't use group by clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am sure there are slicker ways to write it for SQL Server 2012, but essentially do a `CROSS JOIN` to get all possible combinations of status and stage (ie 25 rows). *Then* do an outer join back to `orders` to get the counts for each combination:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd0d6/1)

<sub>** Generally best to avoid using keywords like `order` for table names</sub>

```
  SELECT osg.OrderStageID, ost.OrderStatusID, COUNT(o.OrderID) AS TotalOrders
  FROM   orderStage osg CROSS JOIN orderStatus ost
             LEFT JOIN [order] o ON o.OrderStageID = osg.OrderStageID
                    AND o.OrderStatusID = ost.OrderStatusID
  GROUP BY osg.OrderStageID, ost.OrderStatusID
```

NB: Be sure to review how [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) operates.

Comment: Done like a boss, thanks a lot. Now I have to figure out how to display this information on the page so the correct CaseStatus/CaseStage text has the correct count next to it e.g. Open (60), Dispatched (10), Closed (20) etc

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display `0` where none exist, you can create a driver table that consists of all combinations, and join to that:

```
SELECT driver.*,SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderStatusID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS OrderCount
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT OrderStatusID FROM Orders) a
           ,(SELECT DISTINCT OrderStageID FROM Orders) b
      ) driver
LEFT JOIN Orders o
 ON driver.OrderStatusID  = o.OrderStatusID
 AND driver.OrderStageID = o.OrderStageID
GROUP BY driver.OrderStatusID
       , driver.OrderStageID
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f67d/6/0)

Comment: Does not work if all combinations are not in the order table.  Thus, the idea of a driver table.  I used a tally table since this could be quick large.  However, a fixed table might be best.

Comment: Indeed, cross-joining between the two independent tables makes more sense, at first read of the question I saw only the orders table referenced.

Answer (score 1):

When answering these types of questions, I like to create a sample table in tempdb.

```
--
--  Create test table
--

-- Just toss away code
USE tempdb;
GO

-- Create a simple table
CREATE TABLE my_orders
(
  my_orderstatus_id int,
  my_orderstage_id int
);
GO
```

If you have not looking into tally table by Jeff Moden, you should.  They are a quick way to do loops in a relational algebra way.  I am loading combinations (1..5)(1..5) for times and (6..10)(6..10) two times.  The number after the go tell how many times to run the TSQL.

```
--
--  Load test table
--

-- Create some data (1-5) x 4 counts
;
WITH cteTally1 (my_number1) AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.name) AS my_number
    FROM 
        sys.objects a 
    CROSS JOIN 
        sys.objects b
),
cteTally2 (my_number2) AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.name) AS my_number
    FROM 
        sys.objects a 
    CROSS JOIN 
        sys.objects b
)
INSERT INTO my_orders 
SELECT my_number1, my_number2 
FROM cteTally1 T1 CROSS JOIN cteTally2 T2
WHERE 
    (T1.my_number1 > 0 AND T1.my_number1 <= 5 ) AND 
    (T2.my_number2 > 0 AND T2.my_number2 <= 5 );
GO 4


-- Create some data (6-10) x 2 counts
;
WITH cteTally1 (my_number1) AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.name) AS my_number
    FROM 
        sys.objects a 
    CROSS JOIN 
        sys.objects b
),
cteTally2 (my_number2) AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.name) AS my_number
    FROM 
        sys.objects a 
    CROSS JOIN 
        sys.objects b
)
INSERT INTO my_orders 
SELECT my_number1, my_number2 
FROM cteTally1 T1 CROSS JOIN cteTally2 T2
WHERE 
    (T1.my_number1 >= 6 AND T1.my_number1 <= 10 ) AND 
    (T2.my_number2 >= 6 AND T2.my_number2 <= 10 );
GO 2

-- Show the data
SELECT * FROM my_orders;
```

Last but not least, a simple group by will get you the count for each combination.

```
--
-- Simple group by will suffice
--

SELECT 
    my_orderstatus_id, 
    my_orderstage_id,
    COUNT(*) as number  
FROM my_orders
GROUP BY 
    my_orderstatus_id, 
    my_orderstage_id;
GO
```

Quick screen shot of output:

[image]

This should answer your particular problem.  But if I did get the requirements wrong, please post back.

**You changed the initial requirement now.**  This is what we call in management a ***SCOPE CHANGE***.

If you know that the combinations are always 10 x 10, create a matrix table or Common Table Expression so that you will always have the combination regardless of a match.

Expand the simple group by to left join to the data and group/order by accordingly.

```
--
-- Report Query
--

-- For missing records
;
WITH cteTally1 (my_number1) AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.name) AS my_number
    FROM 
        sys.objects a 
    CROSS JOIN 
        sys.objects b
),
cteTally2 (my_number2) AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.name) AS my_number
    FROM 
        sys.objects a 
    CROSS JOIN 
        sys.objects b
),
cteMissingCombos (my_orderstatus_id, my_orderstage_id) AS 
(
    SELECT T1.my_number1, T2.my_number2
    FROM cteTally1 T1 CROSS JOIN cteTally2 T2
    WHERE T1.my_number1 < 11 AND T2.my_number2 < 11
)

-- Return null if no records, use coalesce if you want 0
SELECT 
    C.my_orderstatus_id, 
    C.my_orderstage_id,
    COUNT(O.my_orderstatus_id) as number  
FROM 
    cteMissingCombos as C LEFT JOIN my_orders as O
ON 
    C.my_orderstatus_id = O.my_orderstatus_id AND 
    C.my_orderstage_id = O.my_orderstage_id
GROUP BY 
    C.my_orderstatus_id,
    C.my_orderstage_id
ORDER BY 
    C.my_orderstatus_id,
    C.my_orderstage_id
GO
```

The output below shows that we did not have combinations for 1 x 6 to 10.  Therefore

[image]

Comment: Will it return a count of zero where the combination does not exist in the Order table?

Comment: That's much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I miss read the requirements - I though you did not have table [OrderStatus] and [OrderStage], just table [Order].  If deletes are allowed on these base tables w/o cascades on Order, the below queries will not work.  Other than that, a cross join for a driver table is the way to go!